# Load all fragments on app opening

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have an app that uses fragments to create a page adapter. I use this to create a swipe tab which loads a different fragment. Each fragment loads webview which displays a specially formatted website. Right now my app only loads the fragments it is on and the ones to the left and right of it. I would like to load all six tabs at once and never again. Is there a way to do this?

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));     
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment=null;
            if(i==0)fragment=new Introduction();
            if(i==1)fragment=new Arena();
            if(i==2)fragment=new Game();
            if(i==3)fragment=new Robot();
            if(i==4)fragment=new Tournament();
            if(i==5)fragment=new Glossary();
            return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 6;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title=new String();
            if(position==0)return "Summary";
            if(position==1)return "The Arena";
            if(position==2)return "The Game";
            if(position==3)return "The Robot";
            if(position==4)return "The Tournament";
            if(position==5)return "Glossary";
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

call [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) with a number higher than half your fragments.
This will force the viewpager to create and keep all of the fragments created as you have in your adapter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // use a number higher than half your fragments.
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));     
}
```

Comment: Good one.. This helped me

Comment: Android API 30 this seems not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin:

```
viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = size / 2
```

by default offscreenPageLimit = 1, meaning it load 1 fragment on both side of current fragment. total 3 frag