# Disable the tabswipe

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am having three tabs which i have created using android.support.v4.view.ViewPager i just want to stop the swipe horizontally by fingers but it should be working when user taps on the name of the tab.

> CalorieBSearchHeading.java

```
public class CalorieBSearchHeading extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private String[] tabs = { "Recent","Frequent","My Foods" };
    private String[] tabss = { "Recent","Frequent","My Drinks" };
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsCalorieBPageAdapter mAdapter;
    private String foodtype;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_caloriebsearchheading);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){

            foodtype = bundle.getString("foodtype");

        }
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagercalorieb);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsCalorieBPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#008080")));
        if(foodtype.equals("Drinks")){
            for (String tab_name : tabss) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }
        else{
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }
        // Adding Tabs


        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalorieMainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

> CalorieBSearchHeading.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pagercalorieb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

> TabOne.java

```
 public class CalorieBTabOneRecentFood extends Fragment{

//here i have done my work
    }
```

And Same for tab two and tab three.
what code i should add to stop swiping by fingers.

Comment: why you want to stop the sliding

Comment: because my listview is repeating the contents on changing the fragments.

Comment: have you checked the page limit?

Comment: no what and where i need to set the limit??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to set the limit in your fragment Activity.

```
 viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Number);
```

Comment: umm...whats the number here??

Comment: This will force the viewpager to create and keep all of the fragments created as you have in your adapter.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958733/load-all-fragments-on-app-opening

Comment: not stop the swipe but resolved my repeatation problem.. thanx

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create your custom  view pager . ex

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

now use this viewpager in your layout like.

```
    <yourclasspackage.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />
```

And now set pageenable in your class.

```
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: it's showing me this error .."The method setPagingEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type ViewPager"

Comment: Sorry for my mistake i updated the code .now check it. it should work.